# When using old SSD on a new laptop, the internet cannot connect

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, ssd

I recently bought a new laptop, and I just took the SSD from the old laptop and use it in the new laptop. So I didn't reinstall windows (8.1 64 bit), it's still the old one, but I did install all the drivers for the new hardwares.

But the problem is that everything is fine except the internet connection always fails.

When i connect to the internet, it just says the connection is limited, no matter at home or at school.

But i clearly successfully logged in the wifi with my school credentials, since if I put the wrong password it would just say cannot connect to the internet instead of saying connection is limited.

And neither the Ethernet or the WIFI works for me.

The hardwares are like this:
Intel Dual Band Wireless AC 7260
Realtek PCIe GBE Family Controller

Thank you.

Comment: Have you run the troubleshooter, if so, what did it say? Does it say the connection type is home/private/public/work? Could you provide some screenshots of the configuration (Network and sharing center -> Network adapters-> Right click on the adapter and select the IPv4 tab? Lastly, consider wiping out the route cache and having it rebuild the routing table: "netsh interface ip delete destinationcache" will do that

Comment: What do you see in the device manager? Is the LAN adapter shown,as working?

Comment: OEM Windows license cannot be transferred to a new PC legally.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot necessarily expect the drive from an old PC to work in a new one because the hardware will be different.

At the least, you need to delete the old network adaptor settings in control panel and then scan for new hardware.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but I did uninstalled the old drivers, and the new wireless adapter is different from the old one